# How do I stop Focus suggestions and summaries?

Tags: notifications, ios

The Focus feature in iOS seems intended to reduce unwanted or distracting notifications, but by default it provides new notifications of its own: suggestions for starting Focus and summaries of notifications accumulated during Focus. Both of these kinds of notifications arrive at precisely the time they are most annoying, respectively disturbing you just as you are starting an activity during which you are likely to want to be undisturbed, or just as you are concluding an activity during which you are in Focus (generally a moment, such as reviewing a workout, that requires the most focus).

How do I disable these Focus suggestions and summaries?

Answer (score 0):

Focus tries to learn your daily routines and apply on-device learning to improve its accuracy; it does get a bit annoying when still in this training mode.

Apple does not offer an option in iOS 15.0x to completely disable Focus, but after a few attempts, it should stop trying to ask you to set any modes up.